# Chrome issue: file://///unc/path/file.xls

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html

I have an "a" tag that is referring to the file UNC path like this in href "file://///unc/path/file.xls" on a c#.MVC web page. The link opens fine in IE but fails in chrome and Firefox with this error: "Not allowed to load local resource: ". This is while debugging the solution in local environment (haven't tried deploying yet).

From my research I have found that chrome doesn't allow opening file with the file protocol for security reasons. I came across a post that suggested allowing the app pool - domain\username access to the folder on UNC. Not sure if that would fix it or if it's just a chrome limitation? Or if there is any other way to make it work in chrome?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: If you have a C# MVC site, why is the page referencing a UNC path instead of something within the site?

Answer (score 0):

First, I agree with JLRishe. If possible, the file should be within the site.

If not possible, you could try the following:

In your controller:

```
    public FileResult Download()
    {
        return File(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"\\UNCPath\test.xls"), System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, "test.xls");
    }
```

In View:

```
    @Html.ActionLink("download", "Download")
```